# std::condition_variable only works while debugging?

Tags: c++, centos, gdb, condition-variable

I wrote a project in C++14, compiled with Intel's icpc on Fedora 26 (gcc 7 dependency). Everything was good and working, until I moved my project onto Centos 7, and began experiencing very mysterious behavior.

On Centos (scl enable devtoolset-7 bash), source code compiles and links without error, but the project only works while debugging with GDB. Without debugging, the condition variable's notification to wake up a sleeping thread don't function.

Multiple worker threads go to sleep, but notification doesn't work, and they don't wake up. But running with GDB, everything works.

I disabled all optimizations. I tried linking libstdc++ and libgcc statically, but nothing worked. I tried a small test program, and the condition_variable worked fine. I also tested Fedora 27, which fixed the problem.

Here is an example:

```
    // worker thread
    // term and cv passed in with std::ref()
    std::atomic<bool> &_terminate = term;
    std::condition_variable &_dataConditionVar = cv;
    std::mutex acctMutex;

    while (!_terminate.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        // do stuff here ....

        // wait for notification
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> acctLock(acctMutex);
        _dataConditionVar.wait(acctLock);   // Thread never wakes up <<
    }
```

Works on Fedora 26/27 but doesn't on Centos 7. Anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you sure that you own the lock to `acctLock` before changing whatever condifion `dataConditionVar` is waiting for? It also seems like you aren't using `dataConditionVar` with any specific condition, which means it's very likely your `wait` is racing with your `notify`. If `notify` happens before `wait`, the `wait` will never see that notification.

Comment: Is your project available online? Alternatively, you should show us more of corresponding code, preferably [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added an example above.

Comment: How do you synchronize threads? Are you sure that the notification on cv cannot happen before `wait` is called? If this happens in all worker threads, they will wait forever, if no other notification is applied after. Moreover, you should also care about spurious wakeups when working with condition variables.

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure, notification cannot happen before wait is called. I debugged for that.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to you problem, but you should generally use your `std::condition_variable` together with a predicate like in the [example on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

Comment: That was my point as well. Note that to work with a predicate, both threads need to share the **same mutex**. In your code it seems the `acctMutex` is local to the worker thread. Anyway, I am no sure we can help you if you don't show us more code, especially how notification is done and which variables are shared.

Comment: See Maxim's answer. The whole point is that with atomic flag, notification can occur between reading the flag and invoking `wait`, which causes deadlock. That's why mutex shared by both threads needs to be used (both with/without predicate version of `wait`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `_terminate` is set after `_terminate.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` but before `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> acctLock(acctMutex);`, `_dataConditionVar.wait(acctLock)` may block forever.

You do not want to use `std::atomic` with `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` because such usage often leads to exactly this race condition. Normally, you use either `std::atomic` or `std::mutex/std::condition_variable`.

The correct usage is to make `_terminate` plain `bool` and access it only when the mutex is held:

```
bool _terminate = false;
std::condition_variable _dataConditionVar;
std::mutex acctMutex;

// Set _terminate example.
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> acctLock(acctMutex);
    _terminate = true;
    _dataConditionVar.notify_one();
}

// Wait for _terminate to be set example.
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> acctLock(acctMutex);
    while(!_terminate)
        _dataConditionVar.wait(acctLock);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I guess I misused condition variable. But what is the correct way to make a worker thread block and consume in a real time application? Without blocking, CPU is pegged at 100% because of the loop, ignoring race conditions on shared data, how can I block a worker thread?

Comment: @HarryReed Note that condition variables are stateless,  `_dataConditionVar.wait` blocks the thread till the next signal. What you rather wait for is state change (in your case the value of `_terminate`), not the signal from the condition variable. Due to [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) the state must be rechecked upon returning from the condition variable wait. Condition variable signal is a merely a hint that the state should be re-evaluated.