# C++11 reading a bool concurrently

Tags: multithreading, c++11, memory-model

When I have a `std::condition_variable cond` and some `bool flag` I can wait for it using a predicate:

```
cond.wait_for(some_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(100), { return flag; })
```

Now I am wondering: Technically C++ only got a proper multi threaded memory model in C++11, and accessing the `flag` variable in a multi threaded context is basically undefined. So I should have to declare it `std::atomic<bool>` to escape that undefined behavior, right?

I am specifically wondering: If I'm NOT declaring it `std::atomic`, can it be that I read stale values from `flag` all the time as the update never makes it to main memory? Or is this a case of "theoretically yes, but practically never happens"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Technically C++ only got a proper multi threaded memory model in C++11, and accessing the flag variable in a multi threaded context is basically undefined.

Accessing a thread-shared variable in C++ is well defined as long as there are no data races. See [Threads and data races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) for more details:

> ... in particular, release of a `std::mutex` is *synchronized-with*, and therefore, *happens-before* acquisition of the same mutex by another thread, which makes it possible to use mutex locks to guard against data races.

---

Mutex lock/unlock constitute acquire/release memory barriers. You do not need `std::atomic` for thread-shared state that is only accessed when the mutex is locked. When a condition notification is received it first locks the mutex, so that you can access the shared state safely.

---

People often introduce data races when they try to use `std::atomic` variables with `std::mutex/std::condition_variable` and access that `std::atomic` without holding the mutex. [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50629479/412080).